# React Native Android Debug APK installed but unsigned doesn't

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

when i built the APK with react native in windows with the **debug** version it worked fine (also in the emulator) and installed in the real device, but when i tried to build with the **release** version i saw the message ( app not installed ) , the problem is i have no way to trace or debug this problem (probably i don't know ), i tried  to fix this problem for about one week ,so i ask for some help here , thanks

```
gradlew assembleDebug --- installed fine
gradlew assembleRelease --- app not installed
```

also i added this lines to gradle.properties file in my project

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=123456
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=123456
```

other details

```
react native version 0.48 ---
my device android version 5.0
windwos version 8.1
the project is AwsomeProject --- the initial projects to test
```

NOTE : in all situations i see the message "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" and the file generated without any problem or any error message

Comment: Just for making sure; have you created the keystore and added the appropriate aliases and passwords right? not just added the lines. Android Studio should give you a error when build not completed successfully. Also it might be related to that you already have the apk installed on the emulator with the debug key. delete the app from device and try again if you didn't already.

Comment: i followed the steps on their website and when i finished i saw this message in the command BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Comment: of course i created keystore file and put it into my project like this image

Comment: Have you tried wiping data of the emulator and trying again?

Comment: https://imgur.com/UgIA1Eg

Comment: the problem not in my emulator, every thing worked fine in the emulator , the problem happened in my real device

Comment: have you tried to manually install the apk to your device?

Comment: this is what i do all the time, i generate the apk then i transfer the apk by the caple from the computed then i click to install the app from my device manually but i still see this error with the release not the debug version

Comment: Just making sure: did you uninstalled previous versions (release version) of the APK before trying to install debug version?

Comment: yes ,for sure i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all about adding this line in the gradle.properties file

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

hope it help someone

Answer (score 2):

`$ cd android && gradlew assembleRelease` creates a signed apk.

*(Note: Don't forget to cd out of `<MyProject>/android` after creating a signed apk back the root of your directory)*

`$ react-native run-android --variant=release` will install the signed apk onto your device

Comment: i generate the apk then i transfer the apk by the caple from the computer then i click to install the app from my real  device manually but i still see this error with the release not the debug version,I want to install it manually because any client hasn't know about react native commands

Comment: Run this command react-native run-android - - variant=release

Comment: also uninstall debug version before installing the release version

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate some certificates to be able to run your signed APK , in the RN docs that is documented.

Please check this out [RN Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)